# UWP: ScrollViewer eats touch events away from children?

Tags: wpf, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

In a Universal Windows App, I have a ScrollViewer, and inside it, I have a canvas.

The canvas is trying to handle its own TouchMove event but it's never fireed unless the parent ScrollViewer is disabled.

How can I make the ScrollViewer not stop the touch events from being passed to its children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set it to cover vertical, horizontal or both of the direction of the gesture by set the `ManipulationMode`. Or else you have to handle all the scrolling manually.

Comment: Thanks. But even when I set Manipulation it still doesn't allow firing of TouchMove event on the child elements.

Comment: You need to listen to `ManipulationDelta` event and process raw input data there.